Why won't my batch file execute this REN line? Is it because of the % in the command?
I am using a CMD batch file to rename hundreds of files with the REN command, but this one file with a "%" in the name is being skipped:
REN "40% @ thesuper.ogg" "ZXS 40% @ thesuper.ogg"

I'm guessing the batch file interpreter is seeing the % as a variable, especially when followed by the @ sign afterwards. The problem is, both % and @ should be there in the filename. Is there a way to force the rename?

I believe what you may be looking for is called "escaping", which is the term for telling the application that what follows is NOT a command character but is just part of a string that it should treat AS a string. I'm not sure how to escape these, but I'd guess that this keyword may help you find the right answer to this.

Thanks, music2myear, your reply lead me to the answer. It seemed that all I had to do was to use "%%" in both cases instead of just the "%". It reminds me of a similar issue in Windows application programming, where the single & was used in the IDE to put an underline in the following character, and so if you wanted to use the & normally, you would put it twice.

Please [edit] the question to include the complete batch file.

Please take our short [tour] and learn how the site is designed to work. Solutions belong to answers, not to questions. And do not litter the title.

@echo off

cd /d "D:\Path\To\Your\Files.ogg"

for /f tokens^=1*delims^=^%% %%i in =;('
     "%WinDir%\System32\where.exe" .:*^%%*.ogg
   ');= do rename "%%~fi%%%%~j" "ZXS 40%%%%~j"


This for /f loop command lists .ogg files that contain the % character in their names. It defines the file name in two parts: the portion before the % and the portion after it. To handle the % correctly in the command, an extra % is added as an escape for the % itself, while the initial % is escaped using ^. This prevents the command interpreter from misinterpreting the double %% as a reference to a variable with no value (null). The original command would fail to rename these files because it doesn’t properly account for the escaping required when handling the % character in file names.
But note that @ does not interfere in any way with the rename command via the command line and/or the batch file.
